# Passing file from web page to wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, file-upload

We have a asp.net page where the user is allowed to upload a file.

This file is then sent on to a back end system via a wcf services.

Currently we read the file into a byte array and then send an object into the wcf service where the byte array is a property.

This works fine, but we are wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [MTOM](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2009/01/wcf-with-mtom-message-encoding.html) which is specifically designed for exchanging binary files because it avoids the overhead of XML serialization. In the example I've linked to a byte array is returned from a WCF operation but you could use it as input argument as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can we avoid reading the file into a byte array in the first place,and send the stream from the browser directly into the wcf service?

Comment: Yes, you could activate [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx). In this case the service operation method will take a Stream as argument to which you could directly write.